# Ajax function always returns an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I have some combos whose load dynamically when you select something in the first one, but when Java method ends (with correct results) allways return an error.

**Select tag**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="countryField" onchange="cargaCombosLocale('new/getProvinceList', 'countryField', 'provinceField')" form="formPerson" class="form-control select2me" placeholder="Pa&iacute;s" th:field="*{person.contactFormAux.country}">                              
        <option value="-1">Pa&iacute;s</option>
        <option th:each="pais : ${paises}" th:value="${pais.id}" th:text="${pais.name}"></option>                                                               
    </select>
</div>
```

**Ajax function**

```
function cargaCombosLocale(lookupUrl, parentSelectElementId, childSelectElementId) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:lookupUrl,
        data:{idPais: $('#' + parentSelectElementId).val()},
        success:function(data){
                var html = '<option value=""></option>';
                var len = data.length;
                for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
                    html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>';
                }

                $('#' + childSelectElementId).html(html);
        },
        error:function(data){
           alert("error");
        },
    });
}
```

**Controller method**

```
@RequestMapping(value="person/new/getProvinceList", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Province> listaProvincias(@RequestParam(value="idPais", required=true) String idPais, Model model ){
        return localeServ.findProvincesByCountry(Long.parseLong(idPais));
    }
```

**Ajax Error**

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string literal at line 1 column
>   27965 of the JSON data

Comment: What kind of error does the AJAX call return?

Comment: I editted main question with the error

Comment: _SyntaxError: JSON.parse_ - you must've missed posting the code where the error actually happens, as there is no JSON.parse in the code you posted

Comment: I didn't use JSON.parse, that's all the code for this action